# Flutter Build Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'

Tags: flutter

I got Android build error like below.
I can build in case of iOS, however somehow I cannot build in case of Android.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.    
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app > project :location                               
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36078

Comment: I fix this problem.
I add code below to my app/build.gradle.


 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'